# Cordova paypal plugin error in running in ios ionicframework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, paypal, ionic-framework

I installed cordova paypal plugin in my ionic framework app, the app is working fine in android but when I try too run for IOS it's showing error build failed,

** BUILD FAILED **

> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileC build/HairDiction.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HairDiction.build/Objects-normal/i386/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.o HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   (1 failure)
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,HairDiction.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,HairDiction,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

and

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:14:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:16:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeProfile;
>                             ^
>                             ;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:16:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeProfile;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:18:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId;
>                             ^
>                             ;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:18:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:20:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopePayPalAttributes;
>                             ^
>                             ;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:20:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopePayPalAttributes;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:22:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail;
>                             ^
>                             ;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:22:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:24:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress;^;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:24:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:26:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopePhone;^;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalOAuthScopes.h:26:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const kPayPalOAuth2ScopePhone;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:6:
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.h:8:
>   In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:16:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalPaymentViewController.h:81:38: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable) [-Wnullability-completeness]
>   @property(nonatomic, weak, readonly) id paymentDelegate; ^
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:6:
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.h:8:
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:17:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalProfileSharingViewController.h:68:39: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable) [-Wnullability-completeness]
>   @property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) id profileSharingDelegate;^
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:6:
>
> In file included from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.h:8:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:21:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentProduction;^;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:21:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:23:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;^;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:23:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:25:27: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;^;
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:25:34: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;
>                              ~~~~~ ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobile.h:21:17: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (__nonnull or __nullable) [-Wnullability-completeness]
>   extern NSString * _Nonnull const PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
>                   ^
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:34:33: error: collection element of type 'int' is not an Objective-C object
>       NSDictionary* clientIds = @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction: clientIdsReceived[@"PayPalEnvironmentProduction"],
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:208:24: error: implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;
>                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:208:22: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *__strong' from 'const int' [-Wint-conversion]
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork;
>                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:210:24: error: implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
>                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:210:22: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *__strong' from 'const int' [-Wint-conversion]
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentProduction;
>                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:212:24: error: implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
>                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:212:22: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSString *__strong' from 'const int' [-Wint-conversion]
>       environmentToUse = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;
>                        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/HairDiction/Plugins/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m:249:16: error: collection element of type 'int' is not an Objective-C object
>       @"openid": kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId,
>                  ^
>   17 warnings and 15 errors generated.

Comment: When you add a plugin always make sure for at least some plugins to work it requires to perform. ionic platform remove ios and 
ionic platform add ios

Comment: Also, make sure you are aware of this https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US

Comment: i did ionic platform remove ios and ionic platform add ios. but still getting same error. i opened the project in xcode it shows implicit conversion of int to 'NSString*' is disallowed in with ARC

Comment: what is your ios cordova version?

Comment: those errors are gone after updating the xcode. now its showing only 1 error that is **_`no visible @interface for 'uiview' declares the selector stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring pushplugin.m`_**. i dont know what was the ios cordova version before. i updated it to 4.0.0

Comment: after you update cordova 4.0 did you try platform remove and add ?

Comment: if you are using pushplugin do a reinstall plugin remove > plugin add > platform remove > platform add

Comment: yes i did it many times. i remove plugin and and platform and added back plugin and platform show long error and build failed message but when i open it in xcode it is showing the above pushplugin error

Comment: i did something in my mac terminal now its asking me sudo permission for every command. :(

Comment: i downgraded the cordova ios version now build is succeeeded but cannot emulate showing this error _`No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):`_

Comment: and this error `Invalid device state

Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HairDiction.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phonegap/hairdiction/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2`

Comment: No target specified for emulator - means your device was not connected/detected while you ran the build using command "ionic run ios", Connect your device and try "ionic run ios --device". Make sure in xcode your device it detected.

Comment: I updated the ios-sim and added the Cordova ios@9.9.2 platform and now it worked

Comment: great, always keep updating cordova and ionic before you start in iOS development :)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Next time I will update everything before starting app development.